# Shared folder file permission <not inherited>

Tags: windows, file, permissions, user-permissions

My permissions for my shared folder (structure: t:\ABC\DEF) displays 3 entries, with the first 2 entries belonging to the same group (X). Both groups "Inherited from" shows "". The first entry, X's permission is "Read & Execute" while the second X's permission is "Special permissions (which includes "Create files/write data" and "Create folders/append data"). Both permissions' type are "Allow".

Can users belonging to X edit/delete files belonging to t:\ABC\DEF?

My user's argument is that they can't as their "inherited from" shows  and they can't even access the folder in the first place. For the third entry, which is "Admin" group, it shows "inherited from" as "t:\ABC\"

Comment: Whether they can edit files depends on the permissions on the files, not the permissions on the folder.  But if they don't have read/execute access to the parent folder, they won't be able to access the child folder via the GUI - they'd have to type in the path to the child folder to reach it.

Comment: @HarryJohnston so this means that they will be able to access the child folder but not the parent folder only?